# Как сделать авторизацию и аутентификацию используя Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, azure

Я создаю WEB API для своего проекта. Но я не понимаю, как делать авторизацию и аутентификацию. Я попытался использовать Identity ASP.NET, но, похоже, Cosmos DB его не поддерживает.
Можете ли вы порекомендовать туториал по аутентификацию и авторизации?

Я использую ASP.NET Core, C#, Cosmos DB и Entity Framework Core Cosmos.

Comment: Определитесь на каком уровне вы хотите проводить проверку для начала. На уровне вашего приложения или на уровне СУБД? Возможны оба варианта и вам необходимо разобраться что именно будете делать. Identity ASP.NET будет защищать ваше веб-приложение от неавторизированных пользователей. Но при этом между веб-приложением и БД может быть совершенно иной способ доступа.
Вот статья по защите Cosmos DB https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data
По Identity https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @Maxim Я хотел проводить проверку на уровне приложения используя JWT токены, но, когда я пытался зарегистрировать пользователя появлялась ошибка. Я её прогуглил и узнал, что похоже Identity не поддерживается. Я так понял, что единственный способ сделать авторизацию и аутентификацию это сделать её на уровне СУБД. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Ошибку бы в топик поста, было бы понятно о чем идет речь. Вот примеры Microsoft Identity platform https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code Если коротко, то суть такова - регистрируете приложение AAD для Web API, затем приложение вашего клиента которое будет аутентифицировать пользователя и получать токен. Во время регистрации укажите что токены с клиента передавать на приложение для Web API. Ваше Web API их проверит и пропустит запрос. Ну а дальше уже пробрасываете все до БД.

Comment: Вот пример, который я лично использовал, когда разбирался с аутентификацией и настройками в AAD, есть WebAPI с облачной аутентификацией и какой-то клиент (в данном случае WPF), но можно заменить и на js https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2